# Get all VM-instances with no labels

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In my Google Cloud console I have set a lot of labels on different kinds of Virtual machines. I want to clean up all the machines that have no label, since those aren't needed anymore. Is there an easy way to filter to get all those machines? When I want to filter now on labels I can only filter for each specific label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gcloud compute instances list --filter=-labels:*` will list the VM instance with no labels.

You obtain this combining [the `gcloud` command to list instances](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/list) with [the filter flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters).

Note the `-` after the equal sign, as this is the logic operator for `NOT` when filtering in `gcloud`. If you delete it, you get the list of instances with labels.

Comment: I just tried this in the google Shell in the google cloud console and it still gave me all my instances, even those with labels

Comment: Compare running both `gcloud compute instances list --filter=-'label'` and `gcloud compute instances list --filter='label'`. The output can't be the same, as the first one lists the ones with no label, and the second one lists the instances with labels. Mind the `-` right after the `--filter=`, it's the key point.

Comment: `compute instances list --filter='label'` gave me 0 items while using `-'label'` gave me all the instances with or without label

Comment: My bad, please check that I edited the command. It's `gcloud compute instances list --filter=-labels:*`

Comment: Is there a way to get the same result on Google Cloud Platform interface?