# Filtering instance based on absense of a label or a tag

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want to make a filter for (service discovery in Prometheus, but it's not important here) based on 'opt-out' idea: everything is 'in' until explicitly asked not to. (The reason that is I don't want to run around and putting opt-in label on everything).

My idea was to filter on absence of a label:

```
filter: '(status="RUNNING") AND NOT (labels.scrape="disable")'
```

Unfortunately, GCE filter system thinks that if there is no 'scrape' label, whole expression is 'false' even if there is 'NOT' in the expression.

I wonder, if there is a way to filter instances based on something which is not present.

Answer (score 0):

This post might get you closer using gcloud?
[Get all VM-instances with no labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210537/get-all-vm-instances-with-no-labels)

There doesn't appear to be an intuitive way to handle this in the GCP Console that I can see.

Assuming your resources aren't already controlled by code (e.g. Terraform), you could write a script speed up labelling the resources into an opt-in model and then ensure that new resources also receive the new label (at which point, opting out is as simple as removing the label).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried about the same approach `--filter 'NO labels:noscrape'`. According to docs it should work, and it work in gcloud, but prom query fails: `Error 503: Internal error. Please try again or contact Google Support. (Code: '5F58A788B6FBD.A2E80C2.81007FB2'), backendError","level":"error","msg":"Unable to refresh target groups`.  Really sad.